# Origin of hyperfine structure Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, atomic-physics

Our course follows a fairly similar approach to [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperfine_structure#Atomic_hyperfine_structure) when introducing the hyperfine Hamiltonian $\Delta H_{HFS} = A_J \vec{I}\cdot \vec{J}$ where $\vec{I}$ and $\vec{J}$ are the (total) angular momenta of the nucleus and electron respectively.

Does this approach not calculate the shift in energy of the nucleus, rather than of the electron? Is that what we really care about (maybe we care about the whole electron + nucleus system?) or is this a shorthand argument and the reverse problem (energy shift in electron due to nuclear magnetic moment) comes out equal? If the latter, how can I see that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correction to the Hamiltonian because of hyperfine interactions is indeed a shift in the Hamiltonian of the *whole atom* (electron+nucleus) as you suggest. 
This is also seen by the fact that the mathematical expression $\mathbf{I}.\mathbf{J}$ itself contains the spin operators of both the electron and the nucleus, meaning that the Hilbert space in question is the Hilbert space of the whole atom, not just the nucleus (or electron).

Comment: But when I go to measure this spectroscopically, do I not only measure differences in the electron's energy? How does the nucleus picking up energy affect spectroscopy at all?

Comment: When doing spectroscopy you measure energy differences in the whole atom as well. A photon with the right frequency induces a transition in the whole atom from one energy level to another. It's not just the electron.

Comment: Note that in the simple case of the hydrogen atom without hyperfine interactions, the assumption is that because the nucleus is much heavier than the electron, you can approximately consider the nucleus to be entirely stationary, meaning that it simply acts as a source for the central Coulomb potential for the electron. Then, transitions for the whole atom correspond to transitions for the electron, which I think where your confusion comes from.

Comment: your comments fix my confusion I think. I'd been considering the electron to get excited in a fixed potential and de-excite, thus it didn't matter what the energy of the source of that potential was. I see that's wrong because the potential is actually an interaction between particles that are both free to move.